# awk sed perl, replacing specific pattern within a range of lines

Tags: replace, sed, awk, block

I'm working in verilog and need to edit a specific line within a unique block, but am unsure of how to proceed

file.v

```
...

    block1 block1(
      .port1(port1),
      .port2(port2),
    );

    block2 block2(
      .(port2)(port2),
      .(port3)(port3)
    );
....
```

I need to somehow remove the " , " for port2 in block1. without modifying block2. There are also multiple blocks else where that contains port2.

```
    block1 block1(
      .port1(port1),
      .port2(port2)
    );
```

I've been trying ranges of awk and sed lines, but not getting the results to modify the file successfully. Any suggestions or solutions is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove any comma that occurs just before the end of a block (whitespace then `);`):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/,(?=\s*\);)//g'
```

Notes:

- `-0777` causes perl to slurp all the input in as a single string. This is required because

  1. we know there's newlines in between so we don't want to read line-by-line
  2. there might be empty lines between the comma and the parentheses so reading by "paragraph" won't work either.
- `-p` causes perl to print the input after modifications.
- the regex is the trickiest part

  - it finds a comma and then looks ahead to match zero or more whitespace characters (includes spaces, tabs, newlines, etc) followed by a close parenthesis and a semicolon.
  - the lookahead text is not part of the matched text (lookaheads are known as "zero width assertions") --  the matched text will be just the comma
  - if there's a match, replace the comma with an empty string.
  - the `g` flag says do this globally in the string.

Comment: thanks, this was more powerful than what I had in mind! Do you think you can explain it more in detail for me? especially how the search for commas account for newlines before the );

Answer (score 1):

This might do the job for you

```
sed '/block1 block1/,/);/{s/\((port2)\),/\1/}' file.v
```

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
awk -v RS="" '/block1/{sub("port2),","port2)")}7' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to remove commas located after a closing paren (`)`) followed by a newline and a closing paren and a semicolon (`);`)?
In this case this might work for you:

```
sed -r ':a;N;s/\),\n\s*\);/)\n);/;P;D;ba'
         | | | |---------| |---|  | | |
         | | |      |        |    | | -- branch to label "a"
         | | |      |        |    | -- delete up to first newline of pattern space
         | | |      |        |    -- print up to first newline of pattern space
         | | |      |        -- replace pattern
         | | |      -- search pattern
         | | -- substitute
         | -- read next line into pattern space (append)
         -- branch label "a"
```